# How does login gain permission to check for secrete files?

Tags: permissions, login

I don't see the sticky bit set for `/usr/bin/login`. Does anybody know how it gains the permission to check for secrete files so that it can check the password of a user?

```
$ ls -lgG $(which login)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 56952 2020/02/07-09:54:14 /usr/bin/login
```

Comment: When would `login` be run as a user process? why would it need to "gain" permission?

Comment: So login always run by root? If it is always run by root, https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/master/src/login.c#L248, why is it necessary to call `access()` here?

Comment: @user15483624 have checked [what `F_OK` means in `access(2)`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/en/man2/access.2freebsd.html#description)?

Comment: @muru Yes. So what?

Comment: @user15483624 being root doesn't make any difference to the existence (or lack thereof) of a given configuration file.